# Passing the hidden value

Tags: php, html, forms

As seen from the code below, I have created an array ($criteria) and out of that array created the headings ($heading) to match the fields in my database.

I am trying to pass the hidden value ($heading) using the name=criteria (see code below)

```
$criteria = array("Independence","Participation","Self Management","Computer Science","Digital Literacy","ICT");
            $arrayLength = count($criteria);
            echo "<form><table>";
            for($count=0;$count<$arrayLength;$count++){
                if($criteria[$count] == 'ICT'){
                    $heading = strtolower($criteria[$count]);
                }else{
                    $heading = lcfirst(str_replace(' ','',$criteria[$count]));
                }

                echo " <tr><td>$criteria[$count]</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>Current Rating: $row[$heading]</tr></td>
                        <input type=hidden name=criteria value=$heading>
                        <tr><td> ". $this->createRatingButtons() ."</td></tr>
                        <tr><td></td></tr><tr><td></td></tr>";
            }
            echo "
                <input type=hidden name=student value=$student>
                <input type=hidden name=unit value=$unit>
                <input type=hidden name=formGroup value=$formGroup>

                </form></table>";
```

Looks like this -

```
Independence
Current Rating: 1
Separate buttons labelled (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) appear here 
Participation
Current Rating: 0
Separate buttons labelled (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) appear here 
Self Management
Current Rating: 0
Separate buttons labelled (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) appear here      
Computer Science
Current Rating: 0
Separate buttons labelled (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) appear here      
Digital Literacy
Current Rating: 0
Separate buttons labelled (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) appear here      
ICT
Current Rating: 0
Separate buttons labelled (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) appear here
```

Buttons are created using the function below, which is called as seen in the code above.

```
public function createRatingButtons(){

            $result = "";
            for($count=1;$count<=6;$count++){
                $result.= "<input type=submit name=rating value=$count> ";
            }
            return $result;

    }
```

**PROBLEM** - When I click the button e.g. under Participation criteria, I press button no. 2, then I can pass the hidden value rating=2 (works fine as seen from the code above), but I also want the criteria for which the rating button was pressed, in this case criteria=participation - but it sends the following -

```
http://localhost/marking/index.php?criteria=independence&criteria=participation&rating=2&criteria=selfManagement&criteria=computerScience&criteria=digitalLiteracy&criteria=ict&student=Liam&unit=Flowol&formGroup=7.8
```

As seen in the link above criteria=independence and criteria=selfManagement etc are all passed! I only want that criteria=participation should be passed as I clicked the button 2 under participation criteria.

Comment: Why are you not quoting the values in your tags? It should be `<input attribute="value" ...`. Also forms should usually be submitted using `POST` request instead of `GET`.  I am starting to suspect that whatever tutorial you are using - it's shit :(

Comment: I suggest you to use "session" not "hidden input". Its secure and new tech.

Comment: @AnandPandey that's a bad suggestion. Especially since, when people use "hidden" inputs, it usually has completely nothing to do with security.

Comment: @tereško: It’s not safe to keep hidden input, because anyone can inspect your input element and find out the information you stored in that hidden input. If you haven’t problem with people to found value of your hidden input then it’s not a big deal, but if you are keeping a secret value which you don’t want to share with anyone then you must not use hidden field. It’s depends on your choice and purpose to use hidden input element.

Comment: @AnandPandey I think you have no idea what you are talking about. Hidden input as **not used for security**. Look at this page. It uses a hidden input in a form to pass IDs of the posts. You are either clueless or malicious.

Comment: @tereško: yes, you are the master and i am a newbie.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171527/discussion-between-anand-pandey-and-teresko).

Comment: @teresko - I prefer GET at the moment, as I am working and debugging the project, it's easier to see the values passed in the URL :) and No I am not using any tutorial. Anyways, any help with the actual problem?

Comment: @AnandPandey - Thanks for the input, but any help with solving the issue?

Comment: @user9825963 that's a stupid reason. Just open developer tool in your browser (by pressing F12), go to "Network" tab and select [preserve log](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/imgs/preserve-log.svg). You will see both POST and GET calls there with all the additional information.

Answer (score 0):

The problem occures, as you can get hinted by the string it produces. The criteria value of each hidden is passed. Your server-side code will parse the query string and will keep only the last value.

You'd prefer having a button named `independence_rating` than having a group of fields depend on each others.

```
public function createRatingButtons($criteria){
        $result = "";
        for($count=1;$count<=6;$count++){
            $result.= "<input type=submit name=\"rating_$criteria\" value=$count />";
        }
        return $result;
}
//Use it by passing the current criteria.
```

Then on the POST:

```
$criterion = array("Independence","Participation","Self Management","Computer Science","Digital Literacy","ICT");
foreach($criterion as $criteria){
    if($_POST['rating_'.$criteria]){
        //Update the rating accordingly
    }
}
```

This would involve looping through all the possible criterion, that could be good if these were checkboxes but they are buttons which means you expect to receive only one at a time. So the simplest would be to create one form for each criteria instead of one big form holding many useless values. If you still want to send the whole form, you could play with arrays instead:

```
public function createRatingButtons($criteria){
        $result = "";
        for($count=1;$count<=6;$count++){
            $result.= "<input type=submit name=\"rating[$criteria]\" value=$count />";
        }
        return $result;
}
//Use it by passing the current criteria.
```

Then on the POST:

foreach($_POST['rating'] as $criteria){
       //Update the rating of $criteria using the post value
       $_POST['rating'][$criteria];
    }

Comment: Hey thanks, but I know I can do it a long way and will take lot of coding lines if I created individual buttons and passed individual values. But I wanted something short and cool and easy :)

Comment: if not, I think I will have to choose a long method :( DO you know how I can make it work with my code above - with some tweakes maybe? Thank you